# How can I create a box in Angular with paragraph on left and right with different color?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

[I have hard time creating this box in Angular, can someone please help me?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snVfv.png)  https://i.stack.imgur.com/snVfv.png

Answer (score 0):

Is it's possible to replace the Paragraph with a normal div. it will be an easy fix.

Just add this HTML and CSS in your component's HTML and CSS file.

I have also created a jsFiddle link for you.

URL - https://jsfiddle.net/Amir_Khan064/m5exo1jc/8/

HTML -

```
<div class="primary-nav">
    <div class="left">Lef aligned div </div>
    <div> right aligned child </div>
</div>
```

CSS -

```
.primary-nav {
    display:-webkit-flex;
    display:flex;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    justify-content:flex-end;
    color: red;
    font-weight: 700
}

.left {
    margin-right:auto;
    color: green;
    font-weight: 700
}
```

[image]